# Use of DecimalStyle

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I fail to understand how DecimalStyle influences my formatting/parsing with DateTimeFormatter.
If I try:

```
date = LocalDateTime.now();
DecimalStyle ds = DecimalStyle.of(Locale.GERMAN);
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy").withDecimalStyle(ds.withDecimalSeparator('?'));
text = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("DecimalStyle: " + text);
```

Shouldn't I get something like: 2.016 in my Output?
What I actually see is that whatever parameters I set to my `ds`, it will never influence the actual formatted String.
This is java 8 API, so there's not much to find on the Internet, unfortunately.

Comment: 2016 got no decimals. Establishing decimal separator got no effect. I've been reading java 8 javadoc about the relation between DecimalStyle and DateTimeFormatter and it's not clear what you obtain setting and specific DecimalStyle applying method withDecimalStyle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DecimalStyle` affects how `0` (zero), `+` (positive), `-` (negative) and `.` (decimal separator) characters are represented. There is no decimal character in `2016` (there could be a thousand separator but DecimalStyle does not handle that).

An example that shows a difference:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
DecimalStyle ds = DecimalStyle.of(Locale.GERMAN);
DateTimeFormatter noDs = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter withDs = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.withDecimalStyle(ds);
System.out.println("Default: " + noDs.format(date));    // Default: 17:44:54.457
System.out.println("German:  " + withDs.format(date));  // German:  17:44:54,457
```

Comment: Brilliant! I see it now. I just focused on years and didn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks!